# How to change the date of Linux to UTC/GMT +1?

Tags: linux, centos, date, centos-5, utc

I need to change the date of my system. I'm running a Linux [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 5.6.

```
# date +%Z
UTC
# date
Thu Oct  6 11:42:45 UTC 2011
```

How do I change the hour to be UTC/GMT +1?

Comment: Read at below link, That will help you for understand.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104088/why-does-tz-utc-8-produce-dates-that-are-utc8

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The normal way is to set your timezone. There are a bunch of files stored by region in the following directory:

```
/usr/share/zoneinfo
```

Take a look and find the one which matches your region. Then you have to create a symlink from `/etc/localtime`:

```
sudo rm /etc/localtime
sudo ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London /etc/localtime
```

Comment: Europe/London is not UTC+1

Comment: I did as you described but `date` still yields the old time? What should be done to sync `date` with `/etc/localtime` ?

Answer (score 5):

You need to change the *timezone*.

- To do it system-wide, symlink `/etc/localtime` to the apropriate file in `/usr/share/zoneinfo`. For example:

  ```
  ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris /etc/localtime
  ```

  In CentOS, you might need to also edit `/etc/sysconfig/clock`.
- To change the timezone just for the current user, set $TZ instead:

  ```
  export TZ="Europe/Paris"
  ```

---

Note that `date -u` **must** always return correct UTC time.

Comment: Isn't "Europe/Paris" the same as CET which differs from UTC+1?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to do this today, using  /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/GMT+1 as link. (CentOS 7.0)
In a strage way, I've got -1 hour.
So I have tried GMT-1, and have now +1 hour.
Looks strange, but works for me.